# Cannot insert the value NULL even though column allows null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, scaffolding, entity-framework-5

I'm testing out scaffolding with Entity Framework in Asp.Net MVC 4 (by following [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx)).  I get it to work fine, except that even though my domain object allows null in a field and the database field allows null I get the error message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsSuccessful', table 'MyTestProject.Persistence.TestContext.dbo.Prediction'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

My domain object looks like this:

```
public class Prediction 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSuccessful { get; set; }
}
```

The generated web page shows IsSuccessful as a drop down box with the choices NotSet, True and False.  In the database the column IsSuccessful allows null.  Still I get the error message.  Everything works fine if I choose True or False (it is saved correctly in the database), but not when I select NotSet.

Surely there must be a way around this?

Some details:

- Visual Studio 2012 RC
- Asp.Net MVC 4
- EntityFramework.dll version 5.0.0.0

Comment: See my second comment to Marc Gravell's answer for the important detail on naming the connection string in web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message looks like it is coming directly from SQL Server. If the server says the column is not nullable, then *the column is not nullable*. It knows best, after all.

Treble check that the column is really nullable in the database. Also consider:

- are you perhaps looking at a different database, with slightly different schema? i.e. one that has not had the correct DDL scripts applied (really easily done)
- are you perhaps looking at a different *object* in the same database? In particular, are you perhaps looking at `Halvard.Prediction`, where-as the code is looking at `dbo.Prediction` ?

Comment: It was NOT connected to the database at all.  How I did not notice that no new entries came I don't know ... Thanks, anyway, as it forced me to check :)

Comment: It defaulted to SQL Express.  Once I changed the name of my connection string to **exactly** match the name of my context class (TestContext) it worked.  There the columns allow null and I got no error messages.